# (C++) Why did boost authors use a struct here instead of a class?

Tags: c++, class, boost, data-structures, struct

In the documentation for the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) [property tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) there is an example of its proper use, [given here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/property_tree/examples/debug_settings.cpp) or in the package in   `libs/property_tree/examples/debug_settings.cpp`.

What I want to know is about the `struct debug_settings` line. Why make this a **struct** instead of a **class**? It even has two member functions, `load(...)` and `save(...)`. I assume that the boost authors have a good reason for this, and that it has something to do with...  efficiency somehow, even if a struct and a class are "technically" identical?

From the copyright year listed, I can guess that this is likely C++98, C++03, or C++0x, so the reasoning for using a struct instead of a class is at least from a pre-C++11 viewpoint.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (C) 2002-2006 Marcin Kalicinski
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. 
// (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at 
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// For more information, see www.boost.org
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//[debug_settings_includes
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
//]
//[debug_settings_data
struct debug_settings
{
    std::string m_file;               // log filename
    int m_level;                      // debug level
    std::set<std::string> m_modules;  // modules where logging is enabled
    void load(const std::string &filename);
    void save(const std::string &filename);
};
//]
//[debug_settings_load
void debug_settings::load(const std::string &filename)
{
    // Create empty property tree object
    pt::ptree tree;

    // Parse the XML into the property tree.
    pt::read_xml(filename, tree);

    // Use the throwing version of get to find the debug filename.
    // If the path cannot be resolved, an exception is thrown.
    m_file = tree.get<std::string>("debug.filename");

    // Use the default-value version of get to find the debug level.
    // Note that the default value is used to deduce the target type.
    m_level = tree.get("debug.level", 0);

    // Use get_child to find the node containing the modules, and iterate over
    // its children. If the path cannot be resolved, get_child throws.
    // A C++11 for-range loop would also work.
    BOOST_FOREACH(pt::ptree::value_type &v, tree.get_child("debug.modules")) {
        // The data function is used to access the data stored in a node.
        m_modules.insert(v.second.data());
    }

}
//]
//[debug_settings_save
void debug_settings::save(const std::string &filename)
{
    // Create an empty property tree object.
    pt::ptree tree;

    // Put the simple values into the tree. The integer is automatically
    // converted to a string. Note that the "debug" node is automatically
    // created if it doesn't exist.
    tree.put("debug.filename", m_file);
    tree.put("debug.level", m_level);

    // Add all the modules. Unlike put, which overwrites existing nodes, add
    // adds a new node at the lowest level, so the "modules" node will have
    // multiple "module" children.
    BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string &name, m_modules)
        tree.add("debug.modules.module", name);

    // Write property tree to XML file
    pt::write_xml(filename, tree);
}
//]

int main()
{
    try
    {
        debug_settings ds;
        ds.load("debug_settings.xml");
        ds.save("debug_settings_out.xml");
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have looked at some previous posts on StackOverflow, but what I am really looking for is *in this instance* only. I have read through

- [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class),
- [Should I use a Struct instead of a lightweight data class for my Linq2Sql data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412747/should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-lightweight-data-class-for-my-linq2sql-data),
- [When to use struct over class in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919292/when-to-use-struct-over-class-in-c?lq=1),
- [When should you use a class vs a struct in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c?rq=1),
- [Structs vs classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543515/structs-vs-classes-in-c?lq=1),
  and
- [Use of class and struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982392/use-of-class-and-struct?lq=1)  .

My thoughts:
To me this doesn't look like "Plain Old Data (POD)", because it has a member function and because it encapsulates class-based objects `std::string` and `std::set`. That string can change so I'm questioning "immutability". It has more than 1 data-type in it and it is likely larger than a 2 bytes. It has access loading and saving functionality which make it more than a simple structure. Boost is a C++ library, so it shouldn't expect that someone will be using it for C.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are equivalent in C++, the only difference is that by default `struct` attributes are `public` while `class` attributes are `private`. The choice is purely a matter of preference.

Comment: @Holt I know that they are "equivalent", but I thought that maybe the resulting machine code could vary _sometimes_, like a++ / ++a. Or if it was purely a style, what their reasoning was.

Comment: If they're equivalent except for the default access specifiers, why would machine code ever vary? Do you expect machine code to vary if you put a redundant `public:` before another `public:` in a struct/class?

Comment: As @JonathanWakely said, there is no difference in generated "code". As for the matter of style, the only person you can ask is the author of the code himself... I personally never use the `class` keyword in c++ (except when I am forced to by the standard... ) for style issue, habits, ..., nobody is going to tell you why **I** do it that way (I am not even sure I could).

Comment: Also note that some of the questions you linked are for C#, which is completely different from C++ and where there are difference between `struct` and `class`.

Answer (score 6):

This class doesn't encapsulate any data; it simply aggregates it together. That, along with convenience functions, looks to be the whole point of the class.

Answer (score 5):

They could do this:

```
class debug_settings
{
public:
    std::string m_file;               // log filename
    int m_level;                      // debug level
    std::set<std::string> m_modules;  // modules where logging is enabled
    void load(const std::string &filename);
    void save(const std::string &filename);
};
```

But they decided that they don't need a class if everything is public anyway.

[As it was already said:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053233/c-why-did-boost-authors-use-a-struct-here-instead-of-a-class/38053913#comment63545260_38053233)

> struct and class are equivalent in C++, the only difference is that by default struct attributes are public while class attributes are private.